# How can you get the docker image size at runtime?

Tags: docker

How can you analyze the size of a Docker container at runtime?

I have a docker image which has 1.5GB.

```
$ docker images 

my-image   latest          36ccda75244c   3 weeks ago     1.49GB
```

Much more space is required on the hard drive while the container is running. How can I get this storage space displayed? With dive or docker inspect etc. you only get the information of the packed image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [docker stats](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/) for that, here's an example:

```
$ docker run --rm -d nginx
e3c2fd

$ docker stats --all --format "table {{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}" --no-stream e3c2fdc
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT
e3c2fdc             0.00%               2.715MiB / 9.489GiB
```